# SQL Server - Como garantir permissão de SELECT para View sem dar permissão nas tabelas base?

Tags: banco-de-dados, sql-server

Preciso de auxílio com um problema envolvendo **permissionamento** de objetos no banco de dados.

Tenho o seguinte cenário:

**1 Banco de Dados**

**4 Esquemas** diferentes com os seguintes proprietários:

- **schemaA**; proprietário **dbo**
- **schemaB**; proprietário **ownerX**
- **schemaC**; proprietário **ownerX**
- **schemaD**; proprietário **ownerX**

Tenho uma visão **viewABC**  que **está em schemaD** e reúne informações de tabelas e visões dos esquemas **schemaA**, **schemaB** e **schemaC**.

Um usuário **userX** terá permissão de `SELECT` em **viewABC**.

Para garantir tal acesso **ownerX** utiliza:

```
GRANT SELECT ON schemaD.viewABC TO userX;
```

Quando **userX** tenta executar o `SELECT` na visão, assim:

```
SELECT * FROM schemaD.viewABC;
```

Temos o seguinte erro:

> A permissão SELECT foi negada no objeto 'tabelaA', banco de
>   dados 'MeuBanco', esquema 'schemaA'.

Entendo que o erro ocorre porque **tabelaA** está num esquema onde **ownerX não é o proprietário** e assim o *SQLServer* aplica as permissões de **userX** para determinar o acesso. Como **userX não tem acesso explícito a tabelaA** a execução da *query* retorna o erro.

Se  **dbo** der a permissão de acesso a *view*, então o erro também acontecerá por **dbo** não ser proprietário dos esquemas **schemaB** e **schemaC**.

Como resolver isso **sem dar permissão de acesso a userX na tabelaA**?

Observações:

- estou usando **SQLServer 2012**
- [não se aplica ao meu caso as soluções propostas aqui...](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/89632/sql-server-grant-select-access-to-a-user-in-a-view-and-not-in-its-tables?newreg=b14d3766dc4d492084da8ef2fbb8aae4)
- [nem aqui...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/368414/grant-select-on-a-view-not-base-table-when-base-table-is-in-a-different-database)
- [pelo que pesquisei meu problema se encaixa em quebra de ownership chains](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188676.aspx)

Comment: Creio que essa pergunta tem relação com o que você deseja: (http://stackoverflow.com/q/4134740/2236741). As referências que você postou sempre envolvem mais de um banco de dados, nesse caso você tem apenas 1.

Comment: @cantoni infelizmente não é o caso. Se eu trocar o proprietário da view para dbo com `ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON schemaD.viewABC TO dbo` então a execução retorna erro por causa das tabelas dos esquemas schemaB e schemaC. E usar a opção `WITH GRANT OPTION` só permitiria ao usuário userX conceder acesso a view a outros usuários. Obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aparentemente não há forma, pelo menos no cenário exposto, de conceder permissão de `SELECT` para **userX** na **viewABC** sem também conceder permissão de `SELECT` na **tabelaA**.

O que pode ser feito é **contornar a situação** utilizando uma [Table-Valued Function](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191165(v=sql.105).aspx) e fazer com que ela **seja executada sempre por um usuário** que tenha permissão de **SELECT** em **todas as tabelas envolvidas** na *query*/*view*.

A solução ficou assim:

- no **schemaD** eu criei uma **função** que retorna o **mesmo conjunto de registros** que a **viewABC** retornava - apesar de **ownerX** não ser o proprietário do **schemaA**, ele tem permissão de `SELECT` na **tabelaA**
- a [cláusula](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188354(v=sql.105).aspx) `EXECUTE AS` foi utilizada para garantir que qualquer execução da função **irá utilizar as permissões do proprietário do esquema** (no caso, o proprietário do **schemaD**, **ownerX**) - neste contexto não importa mais as permissões que **userX** tem ou não na **tabelaA**
- para **userX** é concedido permissão de `SELECT` na função criada - apesar de ser uma função não é a permissão de `EXECUTE` que deve ser utilizada, pois a **função retorna uma tabela**

---

Para ilustrar, um exemplo da **Table-Valued Function**

```
CREATE FUNCTION schemaD.udfABC ()
RETURNS @tabABC TABLE (
  fieldA INT NOT NULL, fieldB INT NOT NULL, fieldC INT NOT NULL
)
WITH EXECUTE AS OWNER
AS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO @tabABC (fieldA, fieldB, fieldC)
    SELECT a.fieldA, b.fieldB, c.fieldC
      FROM schemaA.tableA a
     INNER JOIN schemaB.tableB b ON a.id = b.idA
     INNER JOIN schemaC.tableC c ON b.id = c.idB;

  RETURN;  
END
```

Agora a permissão de `SELECT` é dada na função:

```
GRANT SELECT ON schemaD.udfABC TO userX;
```

E **userX** pode recuperar as informações desejadas assim:

```
SELECT * FROM schemaD.udfABC();
```

---

Se ainda quisermos utilizar a **viewABC** podemos fazer com que ela execute a função, assim:

```
CREATE VIEW schemaD.viewABC
AS
SELECT * 
  FROM schemaD.udfABC();
```

E então a permissão de `SELECT` é dada na *view*, como antes:

```
GRANT SELECT ON schemaD.viewABC TO userX;
```

Usando esta abordagem não é necessário dar permissão direto na função e **userX** vai usar a *view* normalmente.

---

Consegui a solução a partir de sugestões recebidas na postagem que fiz desta mesma [questão](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/143157/sql-server-how-to-grant-select-permission-on-view-that-access-data-in-schemas) no https://dba.stackexchange.com/ e em uma [questão parecida](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/143157/sql-server-how-to-grant-select-permission-on-view-that-access-data-in-schemas) que encontrei lá também.